# F# Performance Profiler Instrumentation Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, profiling

I have a Visual Studio project that contains a C# windows application which references an F# class. When I run the Visual Studio 2010 performance profiler in instrumentation mode I get no instrumentation information for the F# class other than where it was called by the C# application.

When I run in sampling mode it works fine.

I’ve tried running the project in VS2012 and get the same issue.

How do I get Visual Studio to show the instrumentation info for the F# class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run in instrumentation mode, the profiler injects a bit of code at the entry/exit points of every method to record the performance data; however, it only injects this profiling code into the assembly you're actually profiling (e.g., your C# application) and not any of the referenced assemblies.

So, you need to profile the F# assembly directly. I'll assume it's a library, in which case you need to specify your C# application as the start program -- so the profiler will start the C# app but will actually instrument and profile the F# library. See the MSDN article [How to: Specify the Binary to Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985644.aspx) for the settings to do this.

Comment: I used the launch performance wizard, selected 'instrumentation' and then 'A dynamic-link library'. I selected the DLL and exe from the folder the exe builds to. One other thing, I had to run it in x86, as it didn't seem to work with any cpu. Thanks for the helo.